# Compare a Dynamic ArrayList with ArrayList! and remove the elements which are not present in Dynamic array

Tags: java, performance, arraylist

I have two `ArrayLists`, `contactModels` and `list`.

The `contactModels` is a Dynamic Arraylist, I need to compare the two list and remove the elements in `list`, which are not present in `contactModels`(DynamicArrayList).

I tried nested loops, and this:

```
  for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)
  {    
    if(!contactModels.get(i).getEmpID().equals(list.get(i).getEmpID()))
       {
        databaseadapter.removeContact(contactModels.get(i));
       }

  }
```

But I can't achieve it.

Comment: Does your code work? If not, what is wrong?

Comment: I can Update the contacts! which already exist in the List but I cant remove contacts which are not in my Dynamic array list!

Comment: You can try removeAll(Collection c) method. It should do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are not testing whether an item in `contactModels` is not present in `list`. instead you are testing whether the item at an index present in `contactModels` not has the same id as the item at the same index in `list`.

this only works if both collections are sorted with respect to the id's and if contactModels has at least as much entries as list.

is that the case for you ? otherwise this might be your problem.

if the items in your collections have `equals` and `hashcode` correctly implemented and are equal if their id's are equal you could use something like this

```
for (<TypeOfYourItems> item : list)
  {    
    if(!contactModels.contains(item))
       {
        databaseadapter.removeContact(item);
       }
  }
```

Comment: My contactModels is a dynamic array list, its entries will change accordingly! it may be equal or less than the list!

Comment: @praneethkumar then you should not work with indizes ... the index in 'list ' might not even exist in 'contactModels'

Comment: @ André R. I just used some thing like this and it worked by using contains method! thanks for guiding me

Answer (score 0):

@Praneeth : There is API provided by Java. So you can use it.
"list.removeAll(contactModels);"

if contactModel is having non primitive element then you can override equals and hash code to tell on what basis your object will be equal.

Now your list will contain only the unique element which is not there in contact models.

So now you don't need to have other method to remove it also.

Comment: the code in the original question showed that for every element in list that was not in contactModels a method on databaseadapter needed to be called ... in this case 'removeAll' won't help.

Comment: You can pass the list and in one shot you will be able to do that unless it is not provided by any third party you can modify it to accept list and in once you can do that.