# Removing duplicates in a array object

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

I have an array object as follows:

details :

```
Array[2]
>0: Object
    Name:"a"
    Desc:"Desc"
>1: Object
    Name:"b"
    Desc:"Desc2"
>2: Object
    Name:"C"
    Desc:"Desc"
```

I want to remove the last object since the "Desc" has the duplicate entry with the first entry.

I tried this approach in javascript,

```
removedup = details.reduce(function(a,b) { if (a.indexOf(b) < 0) a.push(b); return a },[]);
```

I want the output, to remove the duplicates and therefore adjust the array size.

details :

```
Array[1]
>0: Object
    Name:"a"
    Desc:"Desc"
>1: Object
    Name:"b"
    Desc:"Desc2"
```

what can I modify in logic?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Compare a Dynamic ArrayList with ArrayList! and remove the elements which are not present in Dynamic array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31378088/compare-a-dynamic-arraylist-with-arraylist-and-remove-the-elements-which-are-no)

Comment: Possible duplicate [Remove duplicate object in array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2218999/remove-duplicates-from-an-array-of-objects-in-javascript)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [`Array#filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and `thisArgs` for a temporary object.

```js
var details = [{ Name: 'a', desc: 'Desc' }, { Name: 'b', desc: 'Desc2' }, { Name: 'C', desc: 'Desc' }, {Name: 'a', desc: 'toString'}],
    removedup = details.filter(function (a) {
        if (!(a.desc in this)) {
            this[a.desc] = true;
            return true;
        }
    }, Object.create(null));

document.write('<pre> ' + JSON.stringify(removedup, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: How about `{Name: 'a', desc: 'toString'}`?

Comment: @georg, what should happen with it?

Comment: @NinaScholz: I guess it should be included in the output.

Comment: @NinaScholz: yep, that's better.

Comment: @NinaScholz or you could use `hasOwnProperty` instead of `in`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var modified = details.filter(function (item) {
    return !details.some(function (item_) {
        return item_ !== item && item_.Desc === item.Desc;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Using loadash

var output =  _.chain(Array).reverse().indexBy('Desc').toArray().value();